# Spring Bean not found after adding a interface to it's declaration

Tags: spring, javabeans

Even after turning on lots of debug this one has me mystified. I have a spring bean defined like this:

```
@Component
public class GraphHistoryLoader {
...
}
```

And I an injecting it into another bean like this:

```
@Component
public class StartupPostProcessor {
    @Autowired
    GraphHistoryLoader historyLoader;
}
```

This works fine with GraphHistoryLoader being instantiated and injected into StartupPostProcessor. However, if I then add an interface to GraphHistoryLoader like this:

```
@Component
public class GraphHistoryLoader implements FXCommandLineAware {
...
}
```

I see GraphHistoryLoader being created by Spring and made available for injection, But then the injection into StartupPostProcessor fails with:

```
Error creating bean with name 'startupPostProcessor':
Injection of auto wired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: au.com.anz.fx.process.GraphHistoryLoader
au.com.anz.fx.process.StartupPostProcessor.historyLoader
```

The weird thing is that I have other classes which also implement the FXCommandLineAware interface and they work just fine. Happily being injected based on their class into other beans. It's something about this particular definition and injection that is causing the failure.

Does anyone have any ideas what to look at?

Comment: Should GraphHistoryLoader be defined using @Bean instead?  I'm not sure what is causing that, but the loader seems more like a bean than a component

Comment: Autowiring works by Type. So try providing a name and use @Qualifier annotation to see if it works. So it may conflict if there are many beans implementing an interface.

Comment: @qualifier also fails to find the component.

Comment: Is that the whole error message?  It looks like you've left some of the diagnostic parts of it out.

Comment: What's the actual cause of the "Could not autowire field" exception?  Are you seeing a ClassCastException?  Does GraphHistoryLoader have any methods that are advised with AOP (for example, @Transactional) but are not part of the interface?

Comment: I ended up finding a reason to remove the offending interface so I don't have any problems now. Never did figure out what the issue was. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Same problem executing a JUnit (spring-test-3.2.13) injecting a bean with interface. Qualifying the injection neither worked for me. However, the injection works when running on webserver :S

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem but additionally I used Spring AOP. This means that `GraphHistoryLoader` from your example is proxied by Spring to achieve AOP handling. Spring uses proxies in two ways. See [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies)

- JDK dynamic proxies. It requires your bean to implement an interface. A proxy is created based on this interface that "wraps" your actual instance of the bean. Because of that you loose concrete type information and all is left is only the interface. This is the reason why spring throws `BeanCreationException`
- CGLIB. I don't know the exact details how this library works but it allows you to proxy classes that do not implement any interface. It cannot proxy a final method or final class.

To switch between these two options, when enabling spring-aop, specify flag `proxy-target-class` in xml.

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <!-- other beans defined here... -->
</aop:config>
```

Or in Java Spring Config class via annotation

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Note that proxies are used in Spring in other modules, like transactions and caches. Then you need to set flag `proxyTargetClass` in corresponding place of module in subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you debug the code, the spring class [ClassUtils.java#isAssignableValue(Class,Class)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#L928) is comparing the actual type of the class versus a "proxy" class (of type com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47). That's why it doesn't work:

```
public static boolean isAssignableValue(Class<?> type, Object value) {
    Assert.notNull(type, "Type must not be null");
    return (value != null ? isAssignable(type, value.getClass()) : !type.isPrimitive());
}
```

So far there is 2 options:

1. Work with interfaces instead of classes (**recommended approach**)
2. Configure AOP and/or transactionManager to proxy classes

Example:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined compoent-scan in the applicationContext xml file. The component-scan scans the package you've declared and if it finds the annotations @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller, or @Configuration will create a bean instance for you.

Please make sure the packages you defined in the component-scan (include the GraphHistoryLoader class package too).

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.*"/>
```

Possible cause is:
The context in which GraphHistoryLoader is declared is neither same context as StartupPostProcessor one, nor a parent context

Comment: Nope. Nice try. Both classes and the interface are all in the same package and loaded from the same component scan.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP defaults to using standard JDK dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied. See [AOP Proxies docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies). So, when your bean implement any interfaces, for proxing JDK `Proxy.getProxyClass` is used and only interfaces methods will be available in created proxy bean.

In order to force class byte-code proxing globally, use AOP configuration in @Andrés answer. Or you can declare this proxy type specially on problem bean:

```
@Component
@Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public class GraphHistoryLoader implements FXCommandLineAware {
    ....
}
```